# Can't access ODBC data source from Matlab's Database Toolbox

Tags: sql, sql-server, matlab, odbc

I use Matlab's Database Toolbox to extract data from a SQL Server database. Today the database admin created a new table, but I can't seem to access it.  The new table contains a schema called dbo, and when I try to access it using Matlab's querybuilder tool, the tool gives the following error:
Unable to get table information from data source
I can access other tables in the database without a problem. Any idea what is causing this problem? I don't have enough familiarity with SQL to diagnose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the admin check that this new table has the same permissions and attributes of a table that you know is working.  If the permissions are messed up, you would not be able to retrieve metadata about it.

Comment: He just tried a different set of permissions and I was able to connect. It wasn't obvious that there were any differences between the permissions that he initially chose, and the permissions in a working table, but there you go. Thanks for the help.